# Is it a bug of grails?

Tags: grails

When I typed these code, it works perfectly.

```
def users = User.getAll(params.userChecked)*.id 
println 'user : ' + users
```

But when I did like this, it shows error

```
def users = User.getAll(params.userChecked)*.id 
println 'user : ' + users 

def x = [1, 2]
x.each(){
  def roles = Role.withCriteria{
      users {
             eq 'id', new Long(80)
            }  
  }  
  println roles                 
}
```

But when I removed above code, the below was normally worked.

```
def x = [1, 2]
x.each(){
  def roles = Role.withCriteria{
      users {
             eq 'id', new Long(80)
            }  
  }  
  println roles                 
}
```

I didn't understand what's wrong ? Here's the error

```
No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.call()...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just replace

```
def users = User.getAll(params.userChecked)*.id
```

with

```
 def usersList = User.getAll(params.userChecked)*.id
```

You have two different list one in hasMany, that name users and another defining in controller that creating confusion just change name . All code will work fine.

```
 def users = User.getAll(params.userChecked)*.id 
    println 'user : ' + users 

    def x = [1, 2]
    x.each(){
      def roles = Role.withCriteria{
          users {
                 eq 'id', new Long(80)
                }  
      }  
      println roles                 
    }
```

Comment: The root of the problem is that when there is a variable named `users` in scope at the point when you call `withCriteria`, the `users { ... }` block inside the criteria closure is treated by Groovy as an invocation of the `call` method of the in-scope `users` object, rather than as an invocation of the `users` method on the criteria builder (the closure delegate).

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230379/592139), the problem is the name clash between the `users` variable in the outer scope and the `users {...}` call inside the criteria closure.  The simplest way to fix this is to rename the variable, but if that is not an option then an alternative fix is to use `delegate.` inside the closure:

```
def roles = Role.withCriteria{
  delegate.users {
    eq 'id', new Long(80)
  }
}
```

This removes the ambiguity and forces Groovy to send the call to the closure delegate (the criteria builder) instead of the variable in the containing scope.  You can use the same trick anywhere else where you have a name clash with a builder, I've had to use it in the past when creating XML with a `MarkupBuilder`.